# A Post is saved twice or more during add_action(save_post)

Tags: plugin-development, actions, save-post

I have added a custom meta box for advanced information for a specific post category, to my create new post page.

Now I recognize, that if I save the post, it writes 2 entries in the db with 2 post_ids.

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'my-plugin_add_custom_box' );
add_action( 'save_post', 'my-plugin_save_postdata' );

my-plugin
function my-plugin_add_custom_box() {
    add_meta_box( 
        'my-plugin_sectionid',
        __( 'my-plugin', 'my-plugin_textdomain' ),
        'my-plugin_inner_custom_box',
        'post' 
    );
}

/* When the post is saved, saves our custom data */
function my-plugin_save_postdata( $post_id ) {
  // verify if this is an auto save routine. 
  // If it is our form has not been submitted, so we dont want to do anything
  if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) 
      return;

  // verify this came from the our screen and with proper authorization,
  // because save_post can be triggered at other times

  if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['my-plugin_noncename'], plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) )
      return;


  // Check permissions
  if ( 'page' == $_POST['post_type'] ) //is this the correct post_type?
  {
    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_page', $post_id ) )
        return;
  }
  else
  {
    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) )
        return;
  }

  // OK, we're authenticated: we need to find and save the data

    //$mydata = $_REQUEST['sports'];
    print($post_id); //prints two post ids e.g. 831 & 832
    //print($mydata); //prints two times content of $mydata
}
```

Why are two records in the tables `wp_posts` are created? And when I update the post, a new record is created with `post_name` post_id-revision (843-revision). What are the advantages for creating a new post type, like *sports* for such kind of posts? My advanced information like `$_REQUEST['sports'];` are planned to be stored in a separate db with a ref to wp_posts.

Thanks in advance & BR,

mybecks

Comment: i have a same issue please define which action to use for save function "update_post".

Answer (score 8):

One of the two IDs might be a post revision. To prevent this behaviour, I always have this checks in my save_postdata function:

```
// Autosave, do nothing
if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) 
        return;
// AJAX? Not used here
if ( defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) && DOING_AJAX ) 
        return;
// Check user permissions
if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) )
        return;
// Return if it's a post revision
if ( false !== wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) )
        return;
```

As you can see, the last condition I use here checks for the post revision. Try to use this in your function, too.

Comment: currently I solved my issue, with using 'update_post'. Thx for your answer I will test it :)

Answer (score 1):

An [Example](https://github.com/bueltge/Add-Language-Box/blob/master/fb-add-language-box.php) for read how to.

In the your function `my-plugin_save_postdata()`do you must update the meta data, use the function `update_post_meta()` for doing this, not more; only the `$_POST` is true. Also, WP save an new entry in the db, if you have not deactivate the revision. All updates of an post, include autosave, create an new post with an new id. You can kill this doing via constant in the `wp-config.php` - `define( 'WP_POST_REVISIONS', FALSE );`

Comment: One problem is, that it currently prints out the values two times for e.g. soccerscoocer or the id 841842. When I add my db insert for my sports table, I have 2 entries in there with the same values, it messes up my table. Would this be solved, if I disable the revisions in wp?

Answer (score -1):

Actually, there are some instructions to be followed.

- Firstly, counter should be set.

global $pr_leasing_counter;
        // If this is just a revision, don't send the email.
        if ( wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) )
            return;
        //  echo '

```
'; print_r( $post );
```

`if ($post->post_type == 'leasing' &&  $pr_leasing_counter!=1 && $update == 1 && $post->post_status == 'publish'  ) {
      $pr_leasing_counter = 1
    }`

- Secondly, this counter will be further set in the condition.

Comment: global $pr_leasing_counter;
  // If this is just a revision, don't send the email.  
  if ( wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) )
   return;
  
   if ($post->post_type == 'leasing' &&  $pr_leasing_counter!=1 && $update == 1 && $post->post_status == 'publish'  ) {
      $pr_leasing_counter = 1
    }

Comment: above is the proper code for same.